# How can I view locking on a server file?

Tags: windows-server-2008, files

We have a database file (foxpro) on a Windows share (2003 server). We're having some problems where the program that writes to this file has to retry as the file is locked. This all happens very quickly and within a few seconds the file is available, but the problem is it shouldn't be locked.

Does anyone know how we can view what's locking it? Any tools available?

Answer (score 3):

ProcessMon from Microsoft/sysinternals should allow you to see what processes are accessing a file:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx